# Textcounter Issue in php and javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I have a textarea and a textcounter. requirement is when i write something on the textarea the textcount should increase or decrease as per the text.But its not happening.The Code is Shown Below.

```
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
<div class="form-group col-md-12">
<div id="div_Description" name="div_Description" >
<div class="form-group col-md-12"  style="padding-left:0px;">
<label>Description</label>
<?php
  echo ('<textarea class="form-control" counter_box="textCounter" char_limit=250  id="Acivity_Details"  id="Acivity_Details" name="Acivity_Details" cols="" rows="2" placeholder="Achievement Details..." 
  onKeyUp="textcounter4(document.Add_Assessment.Activity_Details,this.lang,250)" 
    lang="textcounter4"   onKeyUp="textcounter4(document.Add_Assessment.Activity_Details,this.lang,250)" style="width:100%;" 
    value="'.$FormVars['Acivity_Details'].'"></textarea>');
 echo('<h5><small id="textcounter4"></small></h5>');
?>
<h5 style="margin:2px 0px;"><small id="textCounter">(250)</small></h5>
<code style="clear:both;" id="Acivity_DetailsError">
    <?php 
        if (array_key_exists('Acivity_Details', $Errors))
        {
            $tmp=$Errors['Acivity_Details'];            
            echo $PageErrors[$tmp][1];  
        }

    ?>
</code>



</div>
```

Any Help Appreciated

Comment: so you want when you enter some symbols to increase counter of letters in area and if you will remove some symbols then you need to decrease counter. Correct?

Comment: do you want to count how much characters text-area has and display that count in text-counter?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look on this example, <kbd>[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/nejanocowo/1/)</kbd>

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#textarea').on('keyup', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); 

    var _len = $(this).val().length;
    $('#counter').text(_len);
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#Acivity_Details').keyup(function() 
    {
        $('#textCounter').text('('+eval( 250- $('#Acivity_Details').val().length)+')');
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jfLLo6n1/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

**HTML**

```
  <textarea id="Acivity_Details"></textarea>
  <div id="textCounter"></div>
```

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#Acivity_Details').on('keyup', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); 
    var len = $(this).val().length;
    $('#textCounter').text(len);
  });
});
```

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/L5ra9pg1/)**

Answer (score 0):

Pure JS:

```
function countSymbols(obj)
{
    var count = obj.value.length;
    document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = count.toString();
}
```

Html:

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
    <label>Text: <textarea onkeyup="return countSymbols(this);" name="t" id="t1"></textarea></label>
    <p>Text counter: <span id="counter">0</span></p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you don't want to do all those echo, stuff, you need to keep the html separate from your logic.
Although with raw php (php without frameworks its little difficult, but you can do it like this.

```
<div class="form-group col-md-12">
  <div id="div_Description" name="div_Description" >
    <div class="form-group col-md-12"  style="padding-left:0px;">
      <label>Description</label>
      <textarea id="text"></textarea>
      <span id="count"></span> charecters
      <code style="clear:both;" id="Acivity_DetailsError">
      <?php 
        render_page_errors($Errors);
      ?>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  // since i am not much of jquery
  var $ = function(selector) {
    var q = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
    if (q.length == 1)
        return q[0];
    else 
        return q;
  };

  $("#area").addEventListener("keyup", function() {
      var a = $("#area");
      $("#count").innerHTML = a.value.length;
  });
</script>
```

and now you can have a file like showpage_helpers.php 
and put your:

```
function dump_page_errors($errors) {
    if (array_key_exists('Acivity_Details', $Errors))
    {
        $tmp=$Errors['Acivity_Details'];            
        return $PageErrors[$tmp][1];  
    }
}
function render_page_errors($errors) {
    $errors = dump_page_errors($errors);
    // and put some for_each block and put the errors in an unordered list maybe
}
```

and autoload this file in your php view file.

in there